# How to use a string for icon bitmap?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter, icons

Is there a way to use a string for the `iconbitmap` in the `Tkinter` (Python 2.7.9) module?

I know that you can prodive a file path (even though I haven't understood where the difference between `default` and `bitmap` as parameters is.

The reason I am asking is because I want to create out of a Python script an `.exe` with `py2exe` (which works), but I would need to create a icon file then to be able to use an icon.

Any workaround or other method is appreciated.

Comment: You can just pass `root.iconbitmap('images/icon.ico')`

Comment: Unless you are actually trying to display the text as the icon?  Not really clear what you're tying to achieve here.

Comment: Load a bitmap without needing a file, so loading it based on a string. I am not sure however if that works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Note to folks using Python 3, see my [supplemental answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68890690/355230) for an alternative that only works in that version.)*

I don't know of any way to pass `iconbitmap()` anything other than a file path in Python 2.x, so here's a workaround that creates a temporary file from a string representation of icon file's contents to pass it. It also shows a way to ensure the temporary file gets deleted.

```
import atexit
import binascii
import os
import tempfile
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ModuleNotFoundError:  # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk


iconhexdata = '00000100010010100000010018006803000016000000280000001000000020' \
              '000000010018000000000040030000130b0000130b00000000000000000000' \
              'ffffff6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c' \
              '6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6dffffffffffff6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c' \
              '6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d' \
              'ffffffffffff6c6c6d6c6c6dffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' \
              'ffffffffffffffffffffff6c6c6d6c6c6dffffffffffff6c6c6d6c6c6dffff' \
              'ff6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6dffffff6c6c6d' \
              '6c6c6dffffffffffff6c6c6d6c6c6dffffff6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c' \
              '6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6d6c6c6dffffff6c6c6d6c6c6dffffffffffff6c6c6d6c6c' \
              '6dfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff2f4f7d6dfe9b8cadb95b2cfedf2f6' \
              '6c6c6d6c6c6dfffffffffffffffffffffffff4f7fac0d4e69bb9d6739dc657' \
              '89ba3e78b03f78af4177ad4276abd2deeaffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' \
              'ffffffffdfe9f24178ad4178ad4178ad5081b17398be9db8d3bed4e6bbd7ec' \
              'add7f3fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff8fafcaac2dac4d3e4df' \
              'e8f1f9fbfdfffffff4fafd91cff520a3f10297eee4f4feffffffffffffffff' \
              'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe7f4fd7fcaf6159def0595ec' \
              '179fec82c7f4bad6f7fdfefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdfeffdb' \
              'f0fd7bc8f6119bed0695eb1a9ded7ecaf5f0f8febfd3f73165e495b1f1ffff' \
              'fffffffffffffffffffffffffff6fbfe2fa6ee0695eb1b9eed86ccf5e8f6fd' \
              'ffffffd2dff93468e5326ae5c7d6f8ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' \
              'ffff96d2f784cbf5eaf6fdffffffffffffe3eafb4275e72c66e4b6caf6ffff' \
              'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' \
              'f3f6fd5784ea2c66e499b5f2ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' \
              'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdfeff7097ed2c66e47a9eeeffffffffff' \
              'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdfeff' \
              '85a7ef2c66e4608cebf9fbfeffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000000000' \
              '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' \
              '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

def on_closing(iconfile):
    try:
        os.remove(iconfile.name)
    except Exception:
        pass

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as iconfile:
    iconfile.write(binascii.a2b_hex(iconhexdata))

# Register a clean-up function.
atexit.register(lambda file=iconfile: on_closing(file))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('stackoverflow!')
root.iconbitmap(iconfile.name)

tk.Label(root, text='Note the custom icon').pack()
tk.Button(root, text='OK', bg='lightgreen', command=root.quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The window displayed will have a custom icon as shown below:

[image: screenshot of tkinter window created]

You didn't ask how to do it, but here's the code I used to convert the original `.ico` file into the Python string variable used in my example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import binascii
try:
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest
except ImportError:
    from itertools import zip_longest

iconfile = 'stackoverflow.ico'  # Path to icon file.
VAR_NAME = 'iconhexdata'
VAR_SUFFIX = ' = '
INDENTATION = ' ' * len(VAR_NAME+VAR_SUFFIX)
MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 80
EXTRA_CHARS = '"" \\'  # That get added to each group of hex digits.
LINE_LENGTH = MAX_LINE_LENGTH - len(INDENTATION) - len(EXTRA_CHARS)


def grouper(chunk_size, iterable):
    """ Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks.
        s -> (s0,s1,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,...s3n-1), ...
    """
    return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*chunk_size, fillvalue='')

with open(iconfile, 'rb') as imgfile:
    hexstr = [chr(x) for x in bytearray(binascii.b2a_hex(imgfile.read()))]

hexlines = (''.join(str(x) for x in group) for group in grouper(LINE_LENGTH, hexstr))

print(VAR_NAME + VAR_SUFFIX, end='')
print((' \\\n' + INDENTATION).join((repr(line) for line in hexlines)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much also for the code to get the string from a `.ico` file. However I think you have to change  

`print (' \\ \n' + INDENT).join((repr(line) for line in hexlines))` to `print (' \\\n' + INDENT).join((repr(line) for line in hexlines))` because else you get this error: `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't notice because my text editor is configured to automatically remove excess whitespace from the end of lines.

Comment: One question: You can delete the tempfile right after setting the icon for Tkinter, can't you? Because it worked and I am just curious if this has any downsites.

Comment: I don't know Tkinter's internals...but you probably could.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your Python 2.7 question, but may be of interest to others nowadays who are using **Python 3**. In the later version of Python the `tkinter` module has an alternative to the `iconbitmap()` function—named `iconphoto()`—that can be used to set the title-bar icon of any tkinter/toplevel window. However, unlike the former method, the image should be the instance of the `tkinter.PhotoImage` class, not only a file path string — and there ***are*** ways to create a `PhotoImage` object from a byte string in the program so there would be no need to use a file at all, even a temporary one as was the case in my original answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
iconimgdata = b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d' \
              b'2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAXpJREFUeNpi+I8V/Pv7fnnrkz' \
              b'Sd1z0J/37/RJZhYsAKGJkEwis4DV1+3jrzYXEjsgwODRA98c1sctrfTmz6vG0' \
              b'WQhzNLd8vTft6uuXvt1cQ7u9Xj5+XOgHd9u3UNogIioZ/v7+9W6b/eirb23nS' \
              b'X8+0/f32Aij48/6lpxkmT7OMflw7ju4HRmZ2fq813MalDH+/fTvZ8GG50bfT9' \
              b'aySckLZ3f9///95+xxIDcgWDPDv64uf12b8vDzt748PDFxCHBrZzPwWHBrOQI' \
              b'8hNPz9/fPeiU1cglK8otI8wlJMLGz/fn/9cXXunyv9f788Eoh9xMgtDVTGAjf' \
              b'12/vnl7dNh7BZOPl5xZVFFbSEZXTZTGazM3yCqEZx0u8fX9/cPfPh6e0PT258' \
              b'efMEqP8/A+O//0z//jPaZ0wQVdRFaMjLzQWyJk2ejOyNH18/f3r95NPrR19e3' \
              b'FV3iCivqoeoYUFWBNGJCSb5ChER0zgAig1oriKgAZd70ADJTgIIMACVtvtL6F' \
              b'X2cAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

import base64
import tkinter as tk  # Python 3

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('stackoverflow!')
root.geometry('225x50')
img = base64.b64decode(iconimgdata)

photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=img)
root.iconphoto(False, photo)

tk.Label(root, text='Note the custom icon').pack()
tk.Button(root, text='OK', bg='lightgreen', command=root.quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here's what the demo looks like running:

[image: screenshot]

---

Here again is the code I used to convert the 16x16 pixel `.png` image file I had into the Python `bytestring` variable used in the code in my example above. Here's a link to the small [`stackoverflow.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j1gM.png) image file being used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import base64
from itertools import zip_longest

imgfilepath = 'stackoverflow.png'  # Path to an image file.
VAR_NAME = 'iconimgdata'
VAR_SUFFIX = ' = '
INDENTATION = ' ' * len(VAR_NAME+VAR_SUFFIX)
MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 79
EXTRA_CHARS = '"" \\'  # That get added to each group of hex digits.
LINE_LENGTH = MAX_LINE_LENGTH - len(INDENTATION) - len(EXTRA_CHARS)


def grouper(chunk_size, iterable):
    """ Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks.
        s -> (s0,s1,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,...s3n-1), ...
    """
    return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*chunk_size, fillvalue='')

with open(imgfilepath, 'rb') as file:
    hexstr = [chr(x) for x in base64.b64encode(file.read())]

hexlines = (''.join(str(x) for x in group) for group in grouper(LINE_LENGTH, hexstr))

print(VAR_NAME + VAR_SUFFIX  + 'b', end='')
print((' \\\n' + INDENTATION  + 'b').join((repr(line) for line in hexlines)))
```

Comment: Great answer! I'd just like to point out that the base64 decoding isn't needed here. `photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=iconimgdata)` works just as well. Hence you can spare the `import base64`