# Why is PIL.UnidentifiedImageError being raised when trying to open an image from an io.bytesIO object?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, byte

In short terms, when trying to open an image using byte data, I unfortunately end up with an error. Here is some of the code for more clarity.

test2.py:

```
logo = b"iVBORw0KGgoAAAA ... "
#(It's 60k characters long don't worry about it)
```

test.py:

```
import test2 as pim
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

sol = io.BytesIO(pim.logo)
image = Image.open(sol)
```

Apparenly for some strange reason, I end up with this error:

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000028D819373D0>
```

I've tried searching on other posts. I found some similar ones, but none of the solutions worked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to "worry" about it — the error is because the image file data in the `logo` bytes are not something PIL recognizes. What is the source of this data?

Comment: @martineau , I converted the image here: https://www.browserling.com/tools/image-to-base64

Comment: I am trying to keep the image data inside the script so it can be ran just by itself and yes, the format is base64 (Note: I am just importing it because I will stick it together later)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68890690/355230) of mine shows how to deal with base64 encoded image data (by using `base64.b64decode()`).

Comment: Yeah, that's great! It works :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

@martineau actually answered the question but here is a quick runup:

**Convert base64 data, use it in a bytesio class and put it into an image:**

```
s = base64.b64decode(pim.logo)
sol = io.BytesIO(s)
image = Image.open(sol)
```